# CSS files not being used when fetched via localhost as resource

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I have a local server running on Tomcat.
There is currently a single landing page, which is some HTML with a simple CSS style.

My problem is, when I try to send the CSS file as a resource from my JAX-RS server, it shows up in the browser, however, it is not used by the browser to style the HTML.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, the CSS is there, it's really simple, but it doesn't change the background.

Now, I tried to do the simplest version possible, where I just put the HTML and CSS in the same folder, and exclude the `localhost` request, just link it together, and it worked.

I send script files via this function:

```
@GET
@Path("/{scriptName}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
public InputStream getScript(@PathParam("scriptName") String scriptName) {
    return ScriptService.getScript(scriptName);
}
```

In my HTML, the way I put it together in the `<head>` part is this:

```
<head>
     <title>Home</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/WebProject/scripts/mycss.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hello">
        This is some text
    </div>
    <div class="hello2">
        It is nice to meet you sir.
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you guys have any idea on why this is happening?
Btw, as a side note, I use the same code to fetch my Vue.js scripts, and they work perfectly fine.

Comment: The most likely reason is that the css file is not retrieved correctly. Do you know how to look at the browser dev tools? Open it up, go to the home page and see if the css page is retrieved. I did a test and it works fine for me. Check that your paths to the file are correct.

Comment: As an aside, this is a horrible way to serve up your static resources. You should let the server serve them up with its default servlet. It will handle all the caching and things like that that you get for free. If you want to serve them up using a Jersey resource method, you will need to implement all of these things yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Regarding the default servlet, do you have any suggestions on where I could look it up for more info? I'm just starting to learn Jersey.

Comment: If you are using Maven as your build system, then all the static files should go in src/main/webapp. This is the root of the static file system. Put the index.html in the root and add a static folder where you will have your css file. If you are not using Maven, it depends on your IDE and its build system as to where you should put your static files. But wherever they should go, it should get built into the location where the static file servlet knows where to find them.